# Slide transition using css3 transition - not smoothing on mobile

Tags: jquery, css, mobile

Html:

```
<div>
   Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
</div>
<button>Toggle Div</button>
```

Css:

```
div {
  overflow:hidden;
  max-height:0;
  width:200px;
 -webkit-transition:max-height linear .5s;
}

div.open {
  max-height:100px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
   $('button').click(function(){
      $('div').toggleClass('open');
   });
});
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/berivehe/1/)

The problem is that the transition in not perfectly smoothing.

I know there is a difference between the transition of "transform" and the transition of the rest of the styles. 
My question is how can I get the same result using the property "transform"?

Comment: Do you notice a difference if you add `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` to your div?

Comment: You can also try adding `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);` to force GPU acceleration

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not working - both of them.